# Using Array or Series to select from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a counter column which contains an integer. Based on that integer I would like to pick one of consecutive columns in my dataframe.

I tried using .apply(lambda x: ..., axis =1) but my solution there requires an extra if for each column I want to pick from.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0 ], [4, 5, 6, 2 ], [7, 8, 9, 1]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])
df2['e'] = df.iloc[:,df2['d']]
```

This code doesn't work because iloc only wants one item in that position and not 3 (df2['d']= [0,2,1]).
What I would like it to do is give me the 0th item in the first row the 2nd item in the second row and the 1st item in the third row. so
df2['e'] = [1,6,8]

Comment: `.iloc[:, df2['d']]` works for me with pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: Was still on 23.4, updating right now. Error was: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

Comment: It works now but doesn't give the expected result. Instead it just takes the first entry of df2['d'] and uses that as a column. so it returnts [1,4,7] instead of [1,6,8]

Comment: That's expected from `iloc[a,b]`: `a` is the row list, `b` is the column list. And `.iloc` will extract a `len(a) * len(b)` dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for something similar to fancy indexing in numpy. In pandas, it is `lookup`. Try this:

```
df2.lookup(df2.index, df2.columns[df2['d']])

Out[86]: array([1, 6, 8])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @PeterLustig: glad I could help :)